# odbcad32.exe Test Connection passes but program connection fails

Tags: odbc, connection-string, openedge, progress-db

I am trying to get a connection string right, and using odbcad32.exe to test the connection.

The trouble is, I get Connection Established, regardless of what password I enter.

This seems pretty useless.

My .NET program fails with Data source name not found and no default driver specified even though odbcad32.exe has no problem getting the connection.

Data Source Name : Test_Blah
Description: Test_Blah
Host Name: blh-housing
Port Number: 5060
Database name: ih
User ID: administrator
Driver: Progress OpenEdge 10.2b Driver
Password: (space)

This is my connection string:

```
    <add name="BlhConnection" connectionString="DSN=Test_Blah;UID=Administrator;PWD=' ' ;" />
```

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

32 bit ODBC Drivers and connections based on those are only accessible by 32 bit clients.

You are not mentioning your OS - but when your client application is a 64 bit application the 32 bit ODBC driver won't work. I am not 100% sure - but I doubt that there is a 64 bit ODBC driver for OpenEdge in 10.2B. On OpenEdge 11 that's no problem.

Comment: The OS is 64-bit. I have demonstrated to my own satisfaction that the program is not at fault, having tested it also on the Live files. The only thing at fault is this test database connections. And why does OBCAD32.exe connect with any password? That is a rubbish test.

Comment: I was able to set up a Linked Server in SQL Server Management Studio, open it & see the tables. However, when I run my Extract application, I still get this error: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Answer (score 0):

I would start by verifying that you have the correct login credentials.  Especially since you state that you get the same result no matter what you use.

The easiest way to verify the credentials is to login to the db server and open a "proenv" session.  Using proenv ensures that all of the Progress environment is correctly set.  If it is a Windows server "proenv" is in the Progress or OpenEdge program group, if the server is UNIX you can run "$DLC/bin/proenv" from the command line.  Once you are running a proenv shell you can then use the "sqlexp" tool that Progress provides to verify your connection string and credentials.  For example:

```
sqlexp -user userName -password passWord -db dbName -S portNum
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do what you suggest. Logging in to DB Server - how? Can't find any proper guide on using proenv.

Comment: The first step is to figure out if the db server is a Windows box or does it run Unix?  Who set up the database?  That person should understand the instructions above.  The point of those commands is to demonstrate that there is a SQL-92 server running on the server and port that you think it is on and that your username and password are correct.  If the test works then the problem lies in your .NET code.  If the test fails then the problem is with the db server configuration information.

Comment: I was able to set up a Linked Server in SQL Server Management Studio, open it & see the tables. However, when I run my Extract application, I still get this error: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified